# CSS displaces two line strings

Tags: html, css

Have a look at this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ArvindSadasivam/v8dtj2ke/1/

divs:

```
 <button class="typeBtn" id="">
        <img class="iconTick" src="images/buttons/iconTick.png" alt="tickIcon" />Flatfront</button>
    <button class="typeBtn" id="">Flatfront TWICE
        <img class="iconTick" src="images/buttons/iconTick.png" alt="tickIcon" />
    </button>
```

CSS:

```
.typeDiv {
    position : relative;
    margin : 20px 0 0 20px;
    font-family : OpenSans-Regular;
}

 .typeBtn {
    position: relative;
    width: 110px;
    height: 40px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #424242;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 1px solid #D7D7D7;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: right;
    font-family: OpenSans-Regular;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    padding: 0px 40px;
    margin: 15px 10px 0px 0px;
}
.iconTick {
    position : absolute;
    width : 25px;
    left : 5%;
    top : 20%;
}
```

I want the Flatfront twice to be on the same position vertically. 
Basically align them properly.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
vertical-align: top;
```

Into your **.typeBtn** Class

Your Class should looks like this

```
.typeBtn {
position: relative;
width: 110px;
height: 40px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #424242;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
border: 1px solid #D7D7D7;
color: #000000;
text-align: right;
font-family: OpenSans-Regular;
font-size: 0.7em;
padding: 0px 40px;
margin: 15px 10px 0px 0px;
vertical-align: top; /*Changed this */
}
```

Comment: It wasn't aligned previously

Comment: Does it work on all browsers? (mainly ios, android, phonegap)

Comment: May be you should take a test

Answer (score 0):

Change the following styles in .typeBtn like

```
padding:0px;
text-align:center;
```

[image]

Comment: If I do that won't the text appear on top of the icon?